# Golfing ASCII-art

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

Let's try to golf this piece of ascii-art representing a golfing man:

```
      '\                   .  .                        |>18>>
        \              .         ' .                   |
       O>>         .                 'o                |
        \       .                                      |
        /\    .                                        |
       / /  .'                                         |
 jgs^^^^^^^`^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Source: JGS - http://www.retrojunkie.com/asciiart/sports/golf.htm

**Rules:**

- No input allowed
- No external resources allowed
- The output must be exactly this text, displayed in a monospace font (OS console, JS console, HTML <pre> tag, ...), including the leading and trailing line-break.
- Surrounding quotes or double-quotes are allowed (the JS console adds double quotes when you output a string, this is okay)

The best answer will be the one using the less **characters** in any language.

Have fun!

Comment: "exactly this text": including the empty line at the beginning? including the empty line at the end? with a trailing new-line or without? (That is, 0, 1 or 2 new-.lines at the end?)

Comment: @m.buettner the output should have exactly one leading line break and one trailing line break/new line. (and quotes if you can't avoid them) :)

Comment: That ASCII looks more like a Cricket shot to me

Comment: @Mr.Alien I saw it in Martin Kleppe's recent talk: https://speakerdeck.com/aemkei/jscamp-dot-ro-minified-javascript-craziness (video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zy-2ruMHdbU)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## CJam, 62 characters

```
"Ⴀ지尦렒>Ä΀ྀ㸀⡅쇋蒧ʸ鿀ʃ케袧Ƽ蟀ʄ導뤷쀂萯Ű⋥ἀ਎밊耧台 ⢙⿶ꝍ㕟劢햟騤꩏脽啎"2G#b128b:c~
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22%01%E1%82%A0%EC%A7%80%E5%B0%A6%EB%A0%92%EE%8C%9F%3E%C3%84%CE%80%E0%BE%80%E3%B8%80%E2%A1%85%EC%87%8B%E8%92%A7%CA%B8%E9%BF%80%CA%83%EC%BC%80%EF%A0%83%EE%84%AB%E8%A2%A7%C6%BC%E8%9F%80%CA%84%E5%B0%8E%EB%A4%B7%EC%80%82%E8%90%AF%C5%B0%E2%8B%A5%E1%BC%80%E0%A8%8E%EB%B0%8A%EF%81%8B%E8%80%A7%E5%8F%B0%C2%A0%E2%A2%99%E2%BF%B6%EA%9D%8D%E3%95%9F%E5%8A%A2%ED%96%9F%E9%A8%A4%EF%9E%9B%EA%A9%8F%E8%84%BD%EE%9A%AC%E5%95%8E%222G%23b128b%3Ac~)

#### Test run

```
$ base64 -d > golf.cjam <<< IgHhgqDsp4DlsKbroJLujJ8+w4TOgOC+gOO4gOKhheyHi+iSp8q46b+AyoPsvIDvoIPuhKvooqfGvOifgMqE5bCO66S37ICC6JCvxbDii6XhvIDgqI7rsIrvgYvogKflj7DCoOKimeK/tuqdjeOVn+WKou2Wn+mopO+em+qpj+iEve6arOWVjiIyRyNiMTI4Yjpjfg==
$ wc -m golf.cjam
62 golf.cjam
$ cjam golf.cjam

      '\                   .  .                        |>18>>
        \              .         ' .                   |
       O>>         .                 'o                |
        \       .                                      |
        /\    .                                        |
       / /  .'                                         |
 jgs^^^^^^^`^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
$
```

#### How it works

`2G#b` converts the preceding string into an integer by considering it a base-65536 number.

`128b:c` converts that integer back to a string (**110 bytes**) by considering it a base-128 number, which `~` then executes:

```
"
^F'^@\^S.^B.^X|^@>^@1^@8^@>^@>^@
^H\^N.^I'^A.^S|^@
^GO^@>^@>^I.^Q'^@o^P|^@
^H\^G.&|^@
^H/^@\^D.(|^@
^G/^A/^B.^@')|^@
^A"2/{)iS*}%"jgs"'^7*'`'^51*N
```

*(caret notation)*

```
2/{)iS*}%
```

splits the string into pairs of two characters and does the following for each pair: Pop the second character of the string, convert it into an integer and repeat the string `" "` that many times.

For example, `".("` becomes `".                                        "`, because the ASCII character code of `(` is 40.

Finally,

```
"jgs"'^7*'`'^51*N
```

pushes the string `"jgs"`, the character `^` repeated 7 times, the character `` ` ``, the character `^` repeated 51 times and a linefeed.

Comment: Really awesome, but when I take the 62char version from the pastebin and "try it online", a line break is missing before the last line "jgs..."

Comment: @xem: Did you copy from the *RAW Paste Data* section? If I copy the formatted code, I get the same result.

Answer (score 15):

### Ruby, 107

I thought I'd actually try to "generate" the image in code (instead of using some existing compression function):

```ruby
S=?\s*351+?^*60
"⠀鰇렜렟쐺⠾롖鱠롢⡷뢋鲝⢰룁⣩볲룸⤢봪봬뤯鴰⥛".chars{|q|S[511&r=q.ord]=(r>>10).chr}
puts S
```

There are some non-printable characters in that array literal.

Here is the hex view of the file, to show the non-printable characters, too:

```
0000000: 533d 3f5c 732a 3335 312b 3f5e 2a36 300a  S=?\s*351+?^*60.
0000010: 22e2 a080 e9b0 87f0 9780 88eb a09c eba0  "...............
0000020: 9ff0 9f80 b8ef a0b9 ec90 baee 80bb efa0  ................
0000030: bcef a0bd e2a0 bef0 9781 87eb a196 e9b1  ................
0000040: a0eb a1a2 f09f 81b6 e2a1 b7f0 93b1 bfef  ................
0000050: a280 efa2 81eb a28b e9b2 9df0 9bb2 9ef0  ................
0000060: 9f82 afe2 a2b0 f097 82b9 eba3 81f0 9f83  ................
0000070: a8e2 a3a9 ebb3 b2f0 9783 b3eb a3b8 f09f  ................
0000080: 84a1 e2a4 a2eb b4aa ebb4 aceb a4af e9b4  ................
0000090: b0f0 9f85 9ae2 a59b f09a a59d f099 b59e  ................
00000a0: f09c b59f f098 85a7 222e 6368 6172 737b  ........".chars{
00000b0: 7c71 7c53 5b35 3131 2672 3d71 2e6f 7264  |q|S[511&r=q.ord
00000c0: 5d3d 2872 3e3e 3130 292e 6368 727d 0a70  ]=(r>>10).chr}.p
00000d0: 7574 7320 53                             uts S
```

Thanks to Ventero for some major improvements! (He basically reduced the code by 50%.)

Comment: Nice effort! I was hoping for answers like that, that don't just gzip the ASCII ;)

Comment: The second line could be `6.times{|i|S[i+1]=' '*55+?|}` to save 2 characters.

Comment: @voidpigeon Ah thanks. I actually started with that, but initially thought I'd need `i` more than once. Good catch!

Comment: Hope you don't mind if I mention a few more ways to shorten this! Using `S.fill{' '*55+?|}` instead saves a few more characters (you'll have to define `S` as `['']*7`, change the `puts` to `puts p,S,p` and subtract 1 from all your y coordinates though). Then, by using varargs in f (`def f(*p,c)`), you can save the `[]` in the function calls. Oh, and you can drop the `()` around `y,x`.

Comment: @Ventero whoa, 20 characters. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you make `S`  one-dimensional, you can save another 55 characters ;) [Here's the code](http://fpaste.org/115664/12428140/) if you don't want to do it yourself.

Comment: @Ventero oh, very good idea. I'll go ahead and steal that. ;)

Comment: @Ventero two more and it's half as long as the ASCII art itself ;)

Comment: Done: http://fpaste.org/115666/45130641/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15539/discussion-between-m-buettner-and-ventero).

Answer (score 13):

## bash + iconv + DosBox/x86 machine code (<del>104</del> <del>97</del> <del>96</del> 95 characters)

```
echo ↾각슈삨੽₲ɻ庲錿ʴ⇍罋곹삄ૃ蘊尧⺓⺂粘ㄾ㸸ਾ岈⺎➉⸠粓蜊㹏褾鄮漧粐蠊蝜꘮੼⾈葜꠮੼⾇⼠⺂ꤧ੼樠獧惇૳|iconv -futf8 -tucs2>o.com;dosbox o*
```

I suggest to put this in a script in an empty directory, it's almost guaranteed that copy-pasting it in a terminal will break everything; even better, you can grab the script [here](https://bitbucket.org/mitalia/pcg/downloads/launcher.sh) ready-made.

Expected output: [image: expected output]

### How it works

The bash part is just a launcher that uses `iconv` to "decompress" a `.com` file from the UTF-8 characters of the script and launches it with DosBox.

Notice that this poses some limitation on the content, as not all the input sequences can be interpreted as UCS-2 with `iconv` not complaining; for example, for some reason many operations involving the `bx` register broke havoc depending on the place where I used them, so I had to work around this problem several times.

Now, the Unicode thing is just to take advantage of the "character count" rules; the actual size (in bytes) of the script is way larger than the original `.COM` file.

The extracted `.com` file is

```
00000000  be 21 01 ac 88 c2 a8 c0  7d 0a b2 20 7b 02 b2 5e  |.!......}.. {..^|
00000010  83 e0 3f 93 b4 02 cd 21  4b 7f f9 ac 84 c0 75 e4  |..?....!K.....u.|
00000020  c3 0a 0a 86 27 5c 93 2e  82 2e 98 7c 3e 31 38 3e  |....'\.....|>18>|
00000030  3e 0a 88 5c 8e 2e 89 27  20 2e 93 7c 0a 87 4f 3e  |>..\...' ..|..O>|
00000040  3e 89 2e 91 27 6f 90 7c  0a 88 5c 87 2e a6 7c 0a  |>...'o.|..\...|.|
00000050  88 2f 5c 84 2e a8 7c 0a  87 2f 20 2f 82 2e 27 a9  |./\...|../ /..'.|
00000060  7c 0a 20 6a 67 73 c7 60  f3 0a 0a 00              ||. jgs.`....|
0000006c
```

and is 108 bytes long. The NASM source for it is:

```
    org 100h

start:
    ; si: pointer to current position in data
    mov si,data
    ; load the character in al
    lodsb
mainloop:
    ; bx: repetition count
    ; - zero at startup
    ; - -1 after each RLE run
    ; - one less than each iteration after each "literal" run
    ; the constant decrement is not really a problem, as print
    ; always does at least one print, and there aren't enough
    ; consecutive literal values to have wraparound

    ; if the high bit is not set, we have a "literal" byte;
    ; we prepare it in dl just in case
    mov dl,al
    ; then check if it's not set and branch straight to print
    ; notice that bx=0 is fine, as print prints always at least one character
    ; test the top two bits (we need the 6th bit below)
    test al,0xc0
    ; to see if the top bit was set, we interpret it as the sign bit,
    ; and branch if the number is positive or zero (top bit not set)
    jge print
rle:
    ; it wasn't a literal, but a caret/space with a repetition count
    ; space if 6th bit not set, caret otherwise
    mov dl,' '
    ; exploit the parity bit to see if the 6th bit was set
    jnp nocaret
    mov dl,'^'
nocaret:
    ; lower 6 bits: repetition count
    ; and away the top bits and move in bx
    ; we and ax and not al because we have to get rid of the 02h in ah
    and ax,3fh
    xchg ax,bx
print:
    ; print bx times
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
    dec bx
    jg print
    ; read next character
    lodsb
    test al,al
    ; rinse & repeat unless we got a zero
    jnz mainloop
end:
    ret
data:
    ; here be data
    incbin "compressed.dat"
    ; NUL terminator
    db 0
```

All this is just a decompresser for `compressed.dat` whose format is as follows:

- if the high bit is not set, print the character as-is;
- otherwise, the low 6 bits are the repetition count, and the second-highest bit specifies if it has to print a space (bit not set) or a caret (bit set).

`compressed.dat` in turn is generated using a [Python script](https://bitbucket.org/mitalia/pcg/src/master/golf/compress.py) from the original text.

The whole thing can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/mitalia/pcg/src/master/golf/).

Answer (score 10):

### Python, 156

```py
print'''
%6s'\%19s.  .%24s|>18>>
%8s\%14s.%9s' .%19s|
%7sO>>%9s.%17s'o%16s|
%8s\%7s.%38s|
%8s/\%4s.%40s|
%7s/ /  .'%41s|
 jgs'''%(('',)*19)+'^'*7+'`'+'^'*51
```

This uses string formatting with space padding for some basic compression.

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, 147

This runs on the command line and outputs directly to the console:

```
php -r 'echo gzinflate(base64_decode("41IAA/UYBUygB0bYQY2doYWdHReMG4OhEwrUsRpRA9Pob2eHRRNccz5OjXAbcboQl0b9GBK0IWnUB0IFPXUFEjRmpRfHQUBCHOmAiwsA"));'
```

Answer (score 6):

## Perl - 127 <del>129</del> <del>130</del> <del>132</del> <del>135</del> <del>137</del> <del>145</del>

```perl
print q(
6'\19.2.24|>18>>
8\14.9'1.19|
7O>>9.17'o16|
8\7.38|
8/\4.40|
7/1/2.'41|
1jgs^^^^^^^`0
)=~s/\d++(?!>)/$"x$&||'^'x51/reg
```

Thanks to **Ventero** and **m.buettner** for their help in my RegEx optimization.

Comment: You can save one character with `s/\d+(?!8?>)/%$&s/rg`

Comment: @Ventero thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You can save another one by using a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html): `/\d++(?!>)/`

Comment: @m.buettner I didn't know that. Learning new things every day :)

Answer (score 4):

### GCC C - 203 bytes

I figured I'd have some fun with this one. This compiles on my version of MinGW and outputs the expected text.

Whitespace added for clarity.

```
char*v="\n ú'\\ í.  . è|>18>>\n ø\\ ò. ÷' . í|\n ùO>> ÷. ï'o ð|\n ø\\ ù. Ú|\n ø/\\ ü. Ø|\n ù/ /  .' ×|\n jgs^ù`^Í\n";
main(g,o,l){
    for(;*v;
        g=!g&*v<0&l?-*v++:g){
        v+=!(l=*v-35);
        putchar((g-=g>0)?o:(o=*v++));
    }
}
```

None of the online code pasting sites allow the use of single byte characters outside the ASCII range, so I had to escape them for an uploaded example. It's otherwise identical though. http://codepad.org/nQrxTBlX

You can always verify it with your own compiler, too.

Answer (score 4):

## LOLCODE, 590 characters

Cuz LOLCODE iz perfik language 4 golfin: iz easy 2 compres an obfuscate an it isnt verbose at all.

```
HAI
HOW DUZ I D C T
I HAZ A O
I HAZ A N ITZ 0
IM IN YR LOOP UPPIN YR N TIL BOTH SAEM N AN T
O R SMOOSH O AN C MKAY
IM OUTTA YR LOOP
FOUND YR O
IF U SAY SO
VISIBLE ""
VISIBLE SMOOSH "  '\" AN D " " 19 AN ".  ." AN D " " 24 AN "|>18>>" MKAY
VISIBLE "    \              .         ' .                   |"
VISIBLE "   O>>         .                 'o                |"
VISIBLE SMOOSH "    \       ." AN D " " 38 AN "|" MKAY
VISIBLE SMOOSH "    /\    ." AN  D " " 40 AN "|" MKAY
VISIBLE SMOOSH "   / /  .'" AN D " " 41 AN "|" MKAY
VISIBLE SMOOSH "jgs^^^^^^^`" AN D "^" 51 MKAY
VISIBLE ""
KTHXBYE
```

Im pritee sure dis werkz, but I doan has an LOLCODE interpretr an http://repl.it's seems 2 not liek funcshuns.

(Tranzlashun generously providd by http://speaklolcat.com's robots cuz I doan speek lolcat)

---

Indented, spaced, and commented version of the code (LOLCODE comments start with BTW):

```
HAI BTW All LOLCODE programs start with HAI
    HOW DUZ I D C T BTW Function declarations follow the form "HOW DUZ I <func-name>[ <func-arg1>[ <func arg2>[ ...]]]". In this case, D is a function that repeats a YARN C (YARN is the equivalent of string in LOLCODE) NUMBR T (NUMBR = int) times.
        I HAZ A O BTW Variable declarations follow the form "I HAZ A <var-name>"

        I HAZ A N ITZ 0 BTW Variables can be intialised when declared by appending " ITZ <init-value>" to the declaration 
        IM IN YR LOOP UPPIN YR N TIL BOTH SAEM N AN T BTW Loops follow the form "IM IN YR LOOP <action> TIL <condition>" where action and condition are "UPPIN YR N" and "BOTH SAEM N AN T", respectively, in this case
            O R SMOOSH O AN C MKAY BTW "R" assigns a new value to a variable. YARN (string) concatenation follows the form "SMOOSH <str-1> AN <str-2>[ AN <str-3>[...]] MKAY"
        IM OUTTA YR LOOP BTW "IM OUTTA YR LOOP" ends LOLCODE loops

        FOUND YR O BTW "FOUND YR <value>" returns a value
    IF U SAY SO BTW "IF U SAY SO" ends functions

    VISIBLE "" BTW "VISIBLE" prints its argument to stdout
    VISIBLE SMOOSH "  '\" AN D " " 19 AN ".  ." AN D " " 24 AN "|>18>>" MKAY BTW The function I wrote above only "pays off" in terms of characters added/saved when repeating 19 or more characters (the function call itself takes 8 characters, assuming a one-character first argument and a 2-digit second one; you need to factor in the added quotes (2 characters), spaces (4) and ANs (4) for 18 total extra characters; and possible SMOOSH/MKAY)
    VISIBLE "    \              .         ' .                   |"
    VISIBLE "   O>>         .                 'o                |"
    VISIBLE SMOOSH "    \       ." AN D " " 38 AN "|" MKAY
    VISIBLE SMOOSH "    /\    ." AN  D " " 40 AN "|" MKAY
    VISIBLE SMOOSH "   / /  .'" AN D " " 41 AN "|" MKAY
    VISIBLE SMOOSH "jgs^^^^^^^`" AN D "^" 51 MKAY
    VISIBLE ""    
KTHXBYE BTW "KTHXSBYE" ends LOLCODE programs
```

Comment: haha, nice compression, like it :D

Answer (score 3):

## Python - <s>205</s> <s>203</s> 197

```
i="""
G^y`G^MsGgGj!G
G|!o'G.!H/!G/!M
G|!n.!J\G/!N
G|!l.!M\!N
G|!VoG'!W.!O>HO!M
G|!Y.!G'!O.!T\!N
G>H8G1G>G|!^.!H.!Y\G'!L
G""".replace('!','G ')
o=''
j=140
while j:j-=2;o+=ord(i[j+1])%70*i[j]
print o
```

The string `i` interleaves the characters in the ascii art with their multiplicites, represented as characters, all in in reverse order. In addition, I save a bit of space by using '!' instead of 'G ' in `i` and then just replacing it.

Answer (score 3):

## Python (145)

```
'eJzjUgAB9RgFTKAHRthBjZ2hhZ0dF5SHphuhSx2rCTVQff52dlj0wPXm49IHtw+n83Do048hQRdCnz4QKuipE6sNqC8rvTgOAhLiSAdcAG/9Ri8='.decode('base64').decode('zip')
```

Not very original, I know.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (*ES6*) <strike>193</strike> 175 bytes

Edit: [Modified RegPack v3](http://jsfiddle.net/8pfLh/) to maintain newlines, use a `for in` loop to save 3 bytes, and removed eval for implicit console output.

```javascript
_="\nx'\\w{. z~|>18>>\n~\\~x.~ 'z{yx O>>~z 'owy~\\xzwxy~/\\{zw~yx / /  .'ww~ y jgs}`}}}}}}}^^\n~x  }^^^^^^^{   z .wy|\nx{{w~~";for(i of "wxyz{}~")with(_.split(i))_=join(pop())
```

## Using xem's unicode compression: 133 characters

```javascript
eval(unescape(escape('').replace(/uD./g,'')))
```

Comment: great! <3 the RegPack's post-processing! psst, you can make it in 143b: http://xem.github.io/obfuscatweet/

Comment: @xem 143 characters, but a lot more bytes

Comment: yes sorry, 143 chars. the question says that you can count chars. anyway, the regpack's approach is more interesting than the unicode-obfuscation ;)

Comment: FWIW, http://mothereff.in/byte-counter is a tool that counts both characters and bytes (as per UTF-8).

Answer (score 2):

### ES6, 155 chars

Just trying anorher approach:

Run this in Firefox's JS console.

Each unicode character has the following form: \uD8[ascii charcode]\uDC[number of repeats].

```
"".replace(/../g,a=>String.fromCharCode(a[c='charCodeAt']()&255).repeat(a[c](1)&255))
```

(Unicode string made with: http://jsfiddle.net/LeaS9/)

Comment: -3: `.replace(/../g,a=>String.fromCharCode(a[c='charCodeAt']()&255).repeat(a[c](1)&255))`

Comment: oh, great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## PHP

Method 1, simpler (139 bytes):

Using a pre-deflated string.

```
<?=gzinflate(base64_decode('41IAA/UYBUygB0bYQY2doYWdHReMG4OhEwrUsRpRA9Pob2eHRRNccz5OjXAbcboQl0b9GBK0IWnUB0IFPXUFEjRmpRfHQUBCHOmACwA='));?>
```

Method 2, encoding runs of spaces into alphabet letters (192 bytes):

```
<?=preg_replace_callback('#[D-NP-Zu]#',function($e){return str_repeat('a'<$e[0]?'^':' ',ord($e[0])-66);},"
H'\U.D.Z|>18>>
J\P.K' .U|
IO>>K.S'oR|
J\I.WS|
J/\F.ZR|
I/ /D.'ZS|
 jgs^^^^^^^`u
")?>
```

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell, <s>192</s> <s>188</s> 119

```
 -join('̠§Üঠ®Ġ®ఠü¾±¸ľРÜܠ®Ҡ§ ®ঠüΠÏľҠ®ࢠ§ïࠠüРÜΠ®ጠüР¯ÜȠ®ᐠüΠ¯ ¯Ġ®§ᒠü êçóϞà᧞'[0..70]|%{"$([char]($_%128))"*(+$_-shr7)})
```

The part above contains a few non-characters. Hex dump:

```
00: 002D 006A 006F 0069 │ 006E 0028 0027 008A  -join('
10: 0320 00A7 00DC 09A0 │ 00AE 0120 00AE 0C20  ̠§Üঠ®Ġ®ఠ
20: 00FC 00BE 00B1 00B8 │ 013E 008A 0420 00DC  ü¾±¸ľРÜ
30: 0720 00AE 04A0 00A7 │ 00A0 00AE 09A0 00FC  ܠ®Ҡ§ ®ঠü
40: 008A 03A0 00CF 013E │ 04A0 00AE 08A0 00A7  ΠÏľҠ®ࢠ§
50: 00EF 0820 00FC 008A │ 0420 00DC 03A0 00AE  ïࠠüРÜΠ®
60: 1320 00FC 008A 0420 │ 00AF 00DC 0220 00AE  ጠüР¯ÜȠ®
70: 1420 00FC 008A 03A0 │ 00AF 00A0 00AF 0120  ᐠüΠ¯ ¯Ġ
80: 00AE 00A7 14A0 00FC │ 008A 00A0 00EA 00E7  ®§ᒠü êç
90: 00F3 03DE 00E0 19DE │ 0027 005B 0030 002E  óϞà᧞'[0.
A0: 002E 0037 0030 005D │ 007C 0025 007B 0022  .70]|%{"
B0: 0024 0028 005B 0063 │ 0068 0061 0072 005D  $([char]
C0: 0028 0024 005F 0025 │ 0031 0032 0038 0029  ($_%128)
D0: 0029 0022 002A 0028 │ 002B 0024 005F 002D  )"*(+$_-
E0: 0073 0068 0072 0037 │ 0029 007D 0029       shr7)})
```

Encoding scheme is RLE with the length encoded above the lower 7 bit, which are the character to display.

Answer (score 1):

### JS (190b) / ES6 (146b) / ES6 packed (118chars)

Run this in the JS console:

JS:

```
"\n7'\\20.3.25|>18>>\n9\\15.10'2.20|\n8O>>10.9 9'o17|\n9\\8.39|\n9/\\5.41|\n8/2/3.'42|\n2jgs^^^^^^^`".replace(/\d+/g,function(a){return 18==a?a:Array(+a).join(' ')})+Array(51).join("^")+"\n"
```

ES6:

```
"\n6'\\19.2.24|>0>>\n8\\14.9'1.19|\n7O>>9.17'o16|\n8\\7.38|\n8/\\4.40|\n7/1/2.'41|\n1jgs58`101\n".replace(/\d+/g,a=>' ^'[a>51|0].repeat(a%51)||18)
```

ES6 packed: (http://xem.github.io/obfuscatweet/)

```
eval(unescape(escape('').replace(/uD./g,'')))
```

Thanks to @nderscore!

Comment: ES6 down to 158: (goes down to 124 chars with unicode compression) `"\n6'\\19.2.24|>18>>\n8\\14.9'1.19|\n7O>>9.17'o16|\n8\\7.38|\n8/\\4.40|\n7/1/2.'41|\n1jgs^^^^^^^\`".replace(/\d+/g,a=>18-a?' '.repeat(a):a)+"^".repeat(50)+"\n"`

Comment: oh, great, I didn't know repeat

Comment: @nderscore don't be sorry it's great :) but the last line seems broken in my Firefox console

Comment: 146: `"\n6'\\19.2.24|>0>>\n8\\14.9'1.19|\n7O>>9.17'o16|\n8\\7.38|\n8/\\4.40|\n7/1/2.'41|\n1jgs58\`101\n".replace(/\d+/g,a=>' ^'[a>51|0].repeat(a%51)||18)` (stackexchange adds invisible line-breaking characters after 41|\‌)

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer and it works. :) I also added another 158b anwser, maybe you'll have an idea to improve it!

Answer (score 1):

## Python - 236

```
s=' ';print('\n'+6*s+"'\\"+19*s+'.  .'+24*s+"|>18>>\n"+8*s+'\\'+14*s+'.'+9*s+"' ."+19*s+"|\n       O>>"+9*s+'.'+17*s+"'o"+16*s+'|\n'+8*s+"\\       ."+38*s+'|\n'+8*s+"/\\    ."+40*s+"|\n       / /  ."+42*s+"|\n jgs^^^^^^^`"+51*'^'+'\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

### ES6, 163b / 127 chars

Yet another approach, thanks to @nderscore.

Execute it in Firefox's console

JS (163b):

```
"\n'\\..|>18>>\n\\. '.|\nO>>    .'o|\n\\.&|\n/\\.(|\n//.')|\njgs<`h\n".replace(/[^'`Og\n>\\,-8j-|]/g,a=>" ^"[a=a.charCodeAt(),a>53|0].repeat(a%53))
```

Packed (127c):

```
eval(unescape(escape('').replace(/uD./g,'')))
```

Comment: I'm sure @nderscore will find an enhancement :)

Comment: I think SE is breaking some of the characters in this solution. Using a similar approach to what I did with your other answer, this goes down to 163: http://jsfiddle.net/2Fbxq/3/

Comment: Well, that's a great enhancement (and a very nice fiddle). I updade the answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 70 UTF-16 chars

```
挣摯湩㩧呕ⵆ㘱䕂
print砧RԘꁌ䘇䇘鶍薡ᶝ谗ꚋꄝᵍᆫ〵ﺍ癶㑘㗁ࣔᆷ஧楱返䄡鈛絆吠叐嘧䠟噣煺М쐤ຑꀀ䜮'.decode(稧楬b')
```

Of course you're probably going to have to use the hex version:

```
23 63 6F 64 69 6E 67 3A 55 54 46 2D 31 36 42 45 0A 00 70 00 72 00 69 00 6E 00 74 00 27 78 9C E3 52 00 03 F5 18 05 4C A0 07 46 D8 41 8D 9D A1 85 9D 1D 17 8C 8B A6 1D A1 4D 1D AB 11 35 30 8D FE 76 76 58 34 C1 35 E7 E3 D4 08 B7 11 A7 0B 71 69 D4 8F 21 41 1B 92 46 7D 20 54 D0 53 27 56 1F 48 63 56 7A 71 1C 04 24 C4 91 0E 00 A0 2E 47 05 00 27 00 2E 00 64 00 65 00 63 00 6F 00 64 00 65 00 28 00 27 7A 6C 69 62 00 27 00 29 00
```

or the base64 version:

```
I2NvZGluZzpVVEYtMTZCRQoAcAByAGkAbgB0ACd4nONSAAP1GAVMoAdG2EGNnaGFnR0XjIumHaFNHasRNTCN/nZ2WDTBNefj1Ai3EacLcWnUjyFBG5JGfSBU0FMnVh9IY1Z6cRwEJMSRDgCgLkcFACcALgBkAGUAYwBvAGQAZQAoACd6bGliACcAKQA=
```

The first "line" of the program declares the UTF-16 encoding. The entire file is UTF16, but the Python interpreter always interprets the coding line in ASCII (it is `#coding:UTF-16BE`). After the newline, the UTF-16 text begins. It simply amounts to `print'<data>'.decode('zlib')` where the text is a deflated version of the target ASCII image. Some care was taken to ensure that the stream had no surrogates (which would ruin the decoding).

Comment: Well, the first line made me think "oh great, someone made unicode python"

Comment: awesome! Can you do the same in ~35b with UTF-32? :)

Comment: `zip` instead of `zlib` may save one char.

Comment: @xem: most characters stop being valid UTF-32 (chars must be <= 0x10ffff).

Comment: @CeesTimmerman: actually the choice of `zlib` rather than `zip` is very purposeful. `zlib` is an even number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

## C# - <strike>354</strike> 332

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
class X
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x= Convert.FromBase64String("41IAA/UYBUygB0bYQY2doYWdHReMG4OhEwrUsRpRA9Pob2eHRRNccz5OjXAbcboQl0b9GBK0IWnUB0IFPXUFEjRmpRfHQUBCHOmAiwsA");
        Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(new DeflateStream(new MemoryStream(x), CompressionMode.Decompress)).ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

A bit golfed:

```
using System;using System.IO;using System.IO.Compression;class X{static void Main(){var x=Convert.FromBase64String("41IAA/UYBUygB0bYQY2doYWdHReMG4OhEwrUsRpRA9Pob2eHRRNccz5OjXAbcboQl0b9GBK0IWnUB0IFPXUFEjRmpRfHQUBCHOmAiwsA");Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(new DeflateStream(new MemoryStream(x),(CompressionMode)0)).ReadToEnd());}}
```

Comment: That's not really golfed if you still have variable names longer than a character in there. Or unnecessary things like `string[] args`.

Comment: Dunno the rules, but there is no other way in C#, and code need to compile so, this is the shortest possible.

Comment: `Main` does not need to have any arguments, it will still compile (in contrast to Java). Removing that and inlining `x` brings this to 333 already. You can save another byte by removing the space between the arguments in the `DeflateStream` ctor. You can use a cast for the enum member: `(CompressionMode)0`, which brings us down to 324. So I'd argue it's not yet the shortest possible ;-)

Comment: Right you are..

Answer (score 1):

**bzip2, 116**

After seeing the CJAM answer, I figured this one should qualify too.

```
$ wc -c golf.txt.bz2 
116 golf.txt.bz2
$ bzip2 -dc golf.txt.bz2

  '\                   .  .                        |>18>>
    \              .         ' .                   |
   O>>         .                 'o                |
    \       .                                      |
    /\    .                                        |
   / /  .'                                         |
jgs^^^^^^^`^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

$
```

I doubt any further explanation is required. :)

Comment: Using [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum) with DEFLATE gets it down to 77 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TdDNSsRAEATgu09RvkDTPd3zE2Fld8E9iaBnL5lMsgjKKpLnjx1/gnXqQ/hSNXWu9XU8z2/Lwr@5wagxwC/FFKWAow3omTMstQKT0tC1XgB6ojX3RCc6@HH1I4gbJXYN0iSjDFJR1L8X5R7Nql99FLA2deN/HjcjrD1KmpBy8R9HUcQhK3S0EaVlhtQsqL2wG5cz3dHz5@0DvdPHZqgbXbaEqfkMCdUQJHVeYd0SOEJbjr5PghuntcD1C9GRdvNmmBtqKcEbZwzZBMYWIMPYoTBXfyj8xSYnDvvj95Zl@QI "Bubblegum – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 190 bytes

```c
r(n,c){while(n--)putchar(c);}f(c){for(char*s="F'\\S.B.X|>18>>\nH\\N.I' .S|\nGO>>I.Q'oP|\nH\\G.ZL|\nH/\\D.ZN|\nG/ /B.'ZN |\n jgs^^^^^^^`";c=*s++;)c>64&&c<91&&c^79?r(c-64,32):r(1,c);r(51,94);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7BCoJAEIZfRTzobumKZZZZG0RkQljhJWSJYkgtagstOmTPbmPN4We@mYH5wMwA6rog0gD6fuWny5FI06T35wPyQ0GA@p8U853eEHDSKsfqXBciZlO2rbg94FzIhRARC3WFxZWQwYrzkG3027r6bQKWLJvOEmLGkqi5sBRryvQkUhCUc1bu/rVXfRi3ynbbp8BdR9Ng5NmYu743we@m6xjdDh0WxEZZvyA92/AcFKyvh5Mk6Ega@AI)

Answer (score 0):

## Vim, 99 keystrokes

```
63i^<Esc>0R jgs<C-O>7l`<Esc>O<Esc>55I <Esc>A|<Esc>Y5PA>18>><Esc>7|R'\<Down>\<Down><Left><Left>O>><Down><Left><Left>\<Down>\<Down><Left><Left><Left>/<Up>/<Down>/<Right><Right>.'<Up>.<Right><Up>.<Right><Right><Up>.<Right><Right><Right><Up>.<Right><Right><Right><Up>.<Right><Right>.<Right><Right><Down>'<Right>.<Down><Right>'o
```

probably golfable

Explanation:

```
63i^<Esc>0R jgs<C-O>7l`<Esc>
Bottom line, 63 '^'s, replace the beginning with ' jgs', then move 7 caracters to the right and replace one character with '`'

O<Esc>55I <Esc>A|<Esc>
Above current line, add one line and insert 55 spaces, then a trailing '|'

Y5PA>18>><Esc>
Copy that line and paste it above five times. Cursor ends up in topmost line. Append '>18>>'

7|R'\<Down>\<Down><Left><Left>O>><Down><Left><Left>\<Down>\<Down><Left><Left><Left>/<Up>/<Down>/<Right><Right>.'<Up>.<Right><Up>.<Right><Right><Up>.<Right><Right><Right><Up>.<Right><Right><Right><Up>.<Right><Right>.<Right><Right><Down>'<Right>.<Down><Right>'o
Go to 7th column, enter Replace-mode, and replace spaces with golfer and golf ball trail. Arrow keys are used to move around, since it uses fewer keypresses to use the arrow keys instead of <C-o>+movement for up to three keypresses.
```