# Integer Emotions

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, number, kolmogorov-complexity

Write a program or function that "reacts" to a given integer *n* (input via function parameter/args/stdin)

The program doesn't care about negative numbers, likes even, dislikes odd numbers and fears the number 13.

It should output the following:

**if n<0:**

```
 --------------------------
 |                        |
 |                        |
(|      _          _      |)
 |                        |
 |                        |
 |                        |
 |                        |
 |       oooooooooo       |
 |                        |
 |                        |
 |                        |
 --------------------------
```

**if n%2 == 0 and n>-1:**

```
 --------------------------
 |                        |
 |                        |
(|      ^          ^      |)
 |                        |
 |                        |
 |                        |
 |     o            o     |
 |       oooooooooo       |
 |                        |
 |                        |
 |                        |
 --------------------------
```

**if n%2 == 1 and n>-1 and n!=13:**

```
 --------------------------
 |                        |
 |                        |
(|      >          <      |)
 |                        |
 |                        |
 |                        |
 |                        |
 |       oooooooooo       |
 |     o            o     |
 |                        |
 |                        |
 --------------------------
```

**if n==13:**

```
 --------------------------
 |                        |
 |                        |
(|     (O)        (O)     |)
 |                        |
 |                        |
 |       oooooooooo       |
 |       o        o       |
 |       oooooooooo       |
 |                        |
 |                        |
 |                        |
 --------------------------
```

The shortest solution in bytes wins.

Comment: 13 is odd. Do we only output one face? Negatives are odd and even...

Comment: @MartinBüttner, in that case the first rule about negative numbers is completely unnecessary. The only priority which actually requires all of the rules is for the first and last ones to have priority over the middle ones.

Comment: @PeterTaylor oops, good point.

Comment: @StandardToaster I edited the output conditions to avoid any misunderstandings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## CJam - 169

```
S24*aB*2li_D=3{_0<2{_2%}?}?\;:X"^^<>__":s"(O)"a2*+2/=~6X3=-{S*_@+_,C\-S*2*+@@++}:F~t7'o5*_7F:MtX3={5Mt6'o_7Ft}*X2<{X2*6+'o_5Ft}*{" |"\+'|+}%S'-26*+aa2*\*_3=1>"()"\*3\tN*
```

Try it at http://cjam.aditsu.net/

High-level explanation:

`S24*aB*` makes a matrix full of spaces, for the face without the edges
`li_D=3{_0<2{_2%}?}?\;:X` reads the number and converts it to 0 (even), 1 (odd), 2 (negative) or 3 (13), storing it in X
`X"^^<>__":s"(O)"a2*+2/=~` selects the eye types (2 strings)
`{S*_@+_,C\-S*2*+@@++}:F` - function F takes 2 strings (say S1, S2) and a number (say N) and makes a 24-char string containing N spaces, S2, other spaces, S1, N spaces
`2 (eyes) 6X3=- (F)~t` puts the eyes line in the matrix
`7'o5*_7F:Mt` puts the common mouth line in the matrix, and also saves it in M
`X3={5Mt6'o_7Ft}*` if X is 3, it puts M again in the matrix, 2 lines higher, and puts the mouth sides in between
`X2<{X2*6+'o_5Ft}*` if X is 0 or 1, it puts the mouth corners in the appropriate position
`{" |"\+'|+}%` adds vertical edges and a space on the left on every line
`S'-26*+aa2*\*` adds the horizontal edges
`_3=1>"()"\*3\t` adds the ears
`N*` adds newline separators

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby, <s>241</s> 224

```
f=->n{s=" #{?-*26}
"
s+=" |#{' '*24}|
"*11+s
s[84]=?(
s[110]+=?)
s[233,12]=m=?O*12
s[91,3]=s[102,3]=n<0?' _ ':n==13?(s[177,12]=m;s[205]=s[216]=?O;'(O)'):(s[203+d=n%2*56]=s[218+d]=?O;" #{n%2<1??^:b=?>} ")
s[103]=?<if b
$><<s}
```

This defines a function to be called like `f[13]`. I'm sure there's a lot of room for improvement, similar what Ventero helped me do [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32971/8478).

Basically, I'm building the rough framework first, and attach ears as well as the mouth. Then I place the eyes depending on the number. While working out the characters to put into the eyes, I also take care of the different mouths so I don't have to check for the type of number again. Finally I need to fix the right eye for odd numbers, because the code above puts the same string into both eyes.

Answer (score 4):

## C# - 349 bytes

Certainly not going to win any awards, but a different way of doing things.

Golfed:

```c#
class P{static void Main(string[]A){int j=64,i,r=0,n=int.Parse(A[0]);for(var f=(n<0?"IDID-TDTD-":n==13?"HDHD(IDIDOJDJD)SDSD(TDTDOUDUD)KIRI JHSJo":n%2<1?"IDID^TDTD^HIHIoUIUIo":"IDID>TDTD<HKHKoUKUKo")+@"JJSJoCBZM BB[M|BA[N-ADAD(\D\D)AA\N AA]N"+"\n";j++<78;)for(i=64;i++<93;System.Console.Write(f[r]))for(r=0;f[r++]>i|f[r++]>j|i>f[r++]|j>f[r++];r++);}}
```

Less golfed:

```c#
class P
{
    static void Main(string[]A)
    {
        int j=64,i,r=0,n=int.Parse(A[0]); // everything is offset by 65 in this program

        for(
            var f=(n<0?"IDID-TDTD-": // this string describes a set of rectangles (x1,y1,x2,y2,ch)
                n==13?"HDHD(IDIDOJDJD)SDSD(TDTDOUDUD)KIRI JHSJo":
                n%2<1?"IDID^TDTD^HIHIoUIUIo":
                "IDID>TDTD<HKHKoUKUKo"
                )+@"JJSJoCBZM BB[M|BA[N-ADAD(\D\D)AA\N AA]N"+"\n";

            j++<78;) // the loop then prints the rectangles to the screen
            for(i=64;i++<93;System.Console.Write(f[r]))
                for(r=0;f[r++]>i|f[r++]>j|i>f[r++]|j>f[r++];r++);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2 - 255

Not *really* short, but I'll post it anyway:

```
n=input()
o='o'
S='  '
w=y=7*S
b=' '+'-'*26+'\n'
p=' |%19s     |\n'
E=p%y*2
v=S+o*10+S
u=z=o+6*S+o
A=a='^ '
if n%2:A='< ';a='> ';u=y;w=z
if n<0:A=a='_ ';u=w=y
if n==13:A=a='(O)';u=w=v;v=S+o+S*4+o+S
print b+E+'(|%8s%11s     |)\n'%(a,A)+E+p%u+p%v+p%w+E+b
```

I miss item assignment for strings in Python! :(
Then one could start with the character matrix and simply modify eyes and mouth.

Comment: Originally I actually learned Ruby for a similar PPCG challenge where I need immutable strings for precisely that reason. :D

Comment: You can do `b=bytearray()` and then `b+'mystring'` will generate a mutable bytearray, which prints the same way as any other string.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 257

Not a winner, but an alternate approach, got quite close! I have hope I can squeeze a few more chars out of it. Builds all the lines piece by piece, using common substrings to really squeeze out the bytes.

```
X,Z=R=" |"
Q=X*5
Y=X*7
A=X+"-"*26
B=R+X*24+Z
n=input()
a,b,c,d,e,f,g=((("^>^<o  o "+Q)[n%2::2],"OO  ()o")[n==13],"__"+Q)[n<0]
for F in(A,B,B,"(|"+Q+e+a+f+Y+X+e+b+f+Q+"|)",B,B,R+Y+g*10+Y+Z,R+Q+c+X+g+Y+X+g+X+c+Q+Z,R+Y+"o"*10+Y+Z,R+Q+d+Y+Q+d+Q+Z,B,B,A):print F
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 202

```
[S'-26*N]:Z[S'|:PS24*PN]:RR'(PS5*qi:XD=X0<-X2%2*+:Y[" ^ "_" > ""(O)"" - "__]=S8*Y[" ^ ""   "" < ""(O)"" - "__]=S5*P')NRRXD=[SPS7*'oA*S7*PN]:QR?Y[[SPS5*'oSC*'oS5*PN]:T_R[SPS7*'oS8*'oS7*PN]RRR]=QY2=TR?RRZ
```