# Interpreted Interpreter

Tags: code-golf, interpreter

Duplicate? I knew somebody must've done this before.

---

Programming a programming language in itself is something that has interested me since I knew what a programming language was. So I thought I'd create a Code Golf challenge for you.

### Challenge

Create an interpreter for a given programming language, programmed entirely in itself. The interpreter should be able to run any valid program in that language, including itself.

#### Inputs:

The program can take it's input as a file passed as a parameter (e.g. `python myfile.py`) or as lines from stdin (`cat myfile.py | python`).

#### Outputs:

Whatever an interpreter would normally output, on the correct streams (stdout, stderr etc.)

### Specifications

- The code needs to be written in an interpretable language, and serve as an interpreter for its own language.
- It can't use an `eval()` function to interpret code.
- It must run any valid program in that language. If the language allows external modules (or includes), it must be able to read those modules.
- This task is code golf. The submission with the least characters that is correct wins. In case of a tie, the solution that was submitted first wins.

#### Loophole remover:

- Yes, if you can interpret Java, Bytecode or HQ9++ in themselves, go ahead!
- In JavaScript / ES, using HTML tags such as `<script>` is not allowed.

Comment: Our default scoring method is *bytes*, not *characters*, because scoring in character will likely get you answers [like this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32996/8478). You are free to choose characters over bytes if you really want to, but I thought I'd let you know about the consequences. ;)

Comment: Seems like this might be a better popularity contest than code golf- there are many extremely degenerate non-general esolangs which have simple solutions to this problem and more interesting languages have no chance of competing.

Comment: Oh well, this contest is over. Loopholes should be *closed* not opened.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I meant bytes! But there's no point editing now, even though the duplicate refers to an old and inactive challenge.

Comment: is tcl `interp create` valid?

Answer (score 10):

## [Nothing](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Nothing), 0 chars

The source code is an empty file. It does nothing, like any Nothing program, therefore it is the correct execution of every such program.

Comment: Nothing doesn't satisfy [our definition of programming language](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2073).

Comment: @Dennis the OP seems to explicitly accept such languages (e.g. HQ9++)

Comment: In that case, nothing beats Nothing.

Comment: @aditsu That was a joke, as there is no way to create an interpreter of HQ9++ in itself. But this is accepted.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript ES6, 44 bytes/chars

```
s=>document.write(`<${t='script>'}${s}</`+t)
```

Defines a function, taking the code string as a parameter.

**How it works:**

This function simply takes the code, wraps it in `<script>` tags, and writes it into the page. It doesn't use the `eval` function at all - the browser simply runs the code when the new `<script>` element is inserted into the page.

**Tested in the FireFox console on the `about:blank` page as follows:**

```
(s=>document.write(`<${t='script>'}${s}</`+t))("alert('hi')")
```

*Yes, this is probably a loophole and as such I don't really expect to win. (It's impossible to beat the Nothing answer, anyway...)*

*If anything, hopefully it shows how it is possible to evaluate code in javascript without the use of the `eval` function.*

Comment: This is a loophole. I'll add it to the Loophole remover.