# Golf bit weaving

Tags: code-golf, permutations, bitwise

**Note: the first half of this challenge comes from Martin Ender's previous challenge, [Visualize Bit Weaving](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/83899/visualise-bit-weaving).**

The esoteric programming language [evil](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Evil) has an interesting operation on byte values which it calls "weaving".

It is essentially a permutation of the eight bits of the byte (it doesn't matter which end we start counting from, as the pattern is symmetric):

- Bit 0 is moved to bit 2
- Bit 1 is moved to bit 0
- Bit 2 is moved to bit 4
- Bit 3 is moved to bit 1
- Bit 4 is moved to bit 6
- Bit 5 is moved to bit 3
- Bit 6 is moved to bit 7
- Bit 7 is moved to bit 5

For convenience, here are three other representations of the permutation. As a cycle:

```
(02467531)
```

As a mapping:

```
57361402 -> 76543210 -> 64725031
```

And as a list of pairs of the mapping:

```
[[0,2], [1,0], [2,4], [3,1], [4,6], [5,3], [6,7], [7,5]]
```

After `8` weavings, the byte is essentially reset.

For example, weaving the number `10011101` (which is `157` in base 10) will produce `01110110` (which is `118` in base 10).

## Input

There are only `256` valid inputs, namely all the integers between `0` and `255` inclusive. That may be taken in any base, but it must be consistent and you must specify it if the base you choose is not base ten.

You may **not** zero-pad your inputs.

## Output

You should output the result of the bit weaving, in any base, which must also be consistent and specified if not base ten.

You **may** zero-pad your outputs.

---

Related: [Visualize Bit Weaving](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/83899/34718)

Comment: Fun fact: this is the challenge I wanted to post originally. Then I drew up the ASCII art to visualise the permutation, and then Sp3000 suggested that rendering that would make a better challenge. ;)

Comment: Can output base be different from input base? When you say "consistent" I understand that as "every possible input in the same base"

Comment: I think that the representation as a cycle would be more useful than the mapping representation.

Comment: I have to say the ASCII art is definitely more fun.

Comment: This could really use some more test cases.

Comment: Would taking input as a singleton list (i.e. `[1]` in Python instead of `1`) be acceptable?

Comment: @Mego I don't like trick questions but yes.

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, and yes.

Comment: Where it says, "You may **not** zero-pad your inputs," that means `00000001` is invalid (should be `1`), correct?

Comment: @SirBidenXVII Correct.

Answer (score 33):

## Python 2.7, <strike>44</strike> -> 36 bytes

```
lambda x:x/4&42|x*2&128|x*4&84|x/2&1
```

Comment: Great first answer, welcome to PPCG! :)

Comment: If you use `|` instead of `+` and mask *after* shifting then you can shave 8 bytes by removing parentheses.

Comment: Since you're new, I'll point out that you can take @PellMell's suggestion to improve your golf and then use `<strike></strike>` around your old byte score to indicate the progress :-)

Comment: [Crossed out 44 is still regular 44.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7427/31716) :(

Answer (score 15):

## Evil, 3 characters

```
rew
```

[Try it online!](http://evil.tryitonline.net/#code=cmV3&input=Pw)

Input is in base 256, (e.g. ASCII), e.g. to enter the digit 63, enter ASCII 63 which is `?`.

Explanation:

```
r          #Read a character
 e         #Weave it
  w        #Display it
```

This *so* feels like cheating.

Comment: ASCII isn't base 256, it's base 128. What encoding is used for ordinals 128-255? Edit: It looks like it just uses the system encoding.

Answer (score 11):

### CJam, <s>15</s> 12 bytes

*Thanks to FryAmTheEggman for saving 3 bytes.*

```
l8Te[m!6532=
```

Input in base 2. Output also in base 2, padded to 8 bits with zeros.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l8Te%5Bm!6532%3D&input=10011101)

#### Explanation

```
l      e# Read the input.
8Te[   e# Left-pad it to 8 elements with zeros.
m!     e# Generate all permutations (with duplicates, i.e. treating equal elements
       e# in different positions distinctly).
6532=  e# Select the 6533rd, which happens to permute the elements like [1 3 0 5 2 7 4 6].
```

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
&8B[2K1B3D5C])
```

Input is in decimal. Output is zero-padded binary.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=JjhCWzJLMUIzRDVDXSk&input=MTU3)

#### Explanation

```
&8B         % Take input number implicitly. Convert to binary array with 8 digits
[2K1B3D5C]  % Push array [2 4 1 6 3 8 5 7]
)           % Index first array with second array. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 7):

## Jelly, 11 bytes

```
+⁹BḊŒ!6533ị
```

Translation of Martin’s CJam answer. [Try it here.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=fOKBuULhuIrFkiE2NTMz4buL&input=&args=MTU3)

```
+⁹BḊ          Translate (x+256) to binary and chop off the MSB.
              This essentially zero-pads the list to 8 bits.
    Œ!        Generate all permutations of this list.
      6533ị   Index the 6533rd one.
```

Comment: I like the zero padding trick.  Elegant.

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), 30 bytes

```
f=n=>n*4&84|n*2&128|n/2&1|n/4&42
```

Comment: Nice abuse of precedence!

Comment: Surely precedence was designed to work this way! It would even work with the bit shifts, but they're longer.

Answer (score 7):

## x86 machine code, 20 bytes

In hex:

```
89C22455C1E002D0E0D1E880E2AAC0EA0211D0C3
```

It's a procedure taking input and returning result via AL register

### Disassembly

```
89 c2                   mov    edx,eax
24 55                   and    al,0x55  ;Clear odd bits
c1 e0 02                shl    eax,0x2  ;Shift left, bit 6 goes to AH...
d0 e0                   shl    al,1     ;...and doesn't affected by this shift
d1 e8                   shr    eax,1    ;Shift bits to their's target positions
80 e2 aa                and    dl,0xaa  ;Clear even bits
c0 ea 02                shr    dl,0x2   ;Shift right, bit 1 goes to CF
11 d0                   adc    eax,edx  ;EAX=EAX+EDX+CF
c3                      ret
```

Answer (score 7):

## C (unsafe macro), 39 bytes

```c
#define w(v)v*4&84|v*2&128|v/2&1|v/4&42
```

## C (function), 41 bytes

```c
w(v){return v*4&84|v*2&128|v/2&1|v/4&42;}
```

## C (full program), 59 bytes

```c
main(v){scanf("%d",&v);return v*4&84|v*2&128|v/2&1|v/4&42;}
```

(returns via exit code, so invoke with `echo "157" | ./weave;echo $?`)

## C (standards-compliant full program), 86 bytes

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){int v;scanf("%d",&v);return v*4&84|v*2&128|v/2&1|v/4&42;}
```

## C (standards-compliant full program with no compiler warnings), 95 bytes

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){int v;scanf("%d",&v);return (v*4&84)|(v*2&128)|(v/2&1)|(v/4&42);}
```

## C (standards-compliant full program with no compiler warnings which can read from arguments or stdin and includes error/range checking), 262 bytes

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main(int v,char**p){v=v<2?isatty(0)&&puts("Value?"),scanf("%d",&v)?v:-1:strtol(p[1],p,10);exit(*p==p[1]||v&255^v?fprintf(stderr,"Invalid value\n"):!printf("%d\n",(v*4&84)|(v*2&128)|(v/2&1)|(v/4&42)));}
```

#### Breakdown

Pretty much the same as a lot of existing answers: bit-shift all the bits into place by using `<<2` (`*4`), `<<1` (`*2`), `>>1` (`/2`) and `>>2` (`/4`), then `|` it all together.

The rest is nothing but different flavours of boiler-plate.

Answer (score 6):

## J, 12 bytes

```
6532 A._8&{.
```

Uses the permute builtin `A.` with permutation index `6532` which corresponds to the bit-weaving operation.

### Usage

Input is a list of binary digits. Output is a zero-padded list of 8 binary digits.

```
   f =: 6532 A._8&{.
   f 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0
   f 1 1 1 0 1 1 0
1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1
```

### Explanation

```
6532 A._8&{.  Input: s
       _8&{.  Takes the list 8 values from the list, filling with zeros at the front
              if the length(s) is less than 8
6532          The permutation index for bit-weaving
     A.       permute the list of digits by that index and return
```

Answer (score 6):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 39 bytes

```
+`^(?!.{8})
0
(.)(.)
$2$1
\B(.)(.)
$2$1
```

Input and output in base 2, output is left-padded.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=K2BeKD8hLns4fSkKMAooLikoLikKJDIkMQpcQiguKSguKQokMiQx&input=MTAwMTExMDE)

### Explanation

```
+`^(?!.{8})
0
```

This just left-pads the input with zeros. The `+` indicates that this stage is repeated until the string stops changing. It matches the beginning of the string as long as there are less than 8 characters in it, and inserts a `0` in that position.

Now for the actual permutation. The straight-forward solution is this:

```
(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)
$2$4$1$6$3$8$5$7
```

However that's painfully long and redundant. I found a different formulation of the permutation that is much easier to implement in Retina (`X` represents a swap of adjacent bits):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 X   X   X   X
2 1 4 3 6 5 8 7
   X   X   X
2 4 1 6 3 8 5 7
```

Now that's much easier to implement:

```
(.)(.)
$2$1
```

This simply matches two characters and swaps them. Since matches don't overlap, this swaps all four pairs.

```
\B(.)(.)
$2$1
```

Now we want to do the same thing again, but we want to skip the first character. The easiest way to do so is to require that the match *doesn't* start at a word boundary with `\B`.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 34 bytes

```
PadLeft[#,8][[{2,4,1,6,3,8,5,7}]]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a list of binary digits, and outputs a padded list of 8 binary digits.

Answer (score 3):

### Matlab, <s>49</s> <s>48</s> 44 bytes

```
s=sprintf('%08s',input(''));s('24163857'-48)
```

Takes input as string of binary values. Output padded.
4 bytes saved thanks to @Luis Mendo.

**Explanation:**

```
input('')             -- takes input
s=sprintf('%08s',...) -- pads with zeros to obtain 8 digits
s('24163857'-48)      -- takes positions [2 4 1 6 3 8 5 7] from s (48 is code for '0')
```

Answer (score 3):

### 05AB1E, <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
žz+b¦œ6532èJ
```

**Explanation**

```
žz+b¦           # convert to binary padded with 0's to 8 digits
     œ6532è     # get the 6532th permutation of the binary number
           J    # join and implicitly print
```

Input is in base 10.
Output is in base 2.

Borrows the permutation trick from [MartinEnder's CJam answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84011/47066)

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xb56K2LCpsWTNjUzMsOoSg&input=MTU3)

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell v2+, 34 bytes

```
("{0:D8}"-f$args)[1,3,0,5,2,7,4,6]
```

Translation of @LegionMammal978's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84015/42963). Full program. Takes input via command-line argument as a binary number, outputs as a binary array, zero-padded.

The `"{0:D8}"-f` portion uses [standard numeric format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) to prepend `0` to the input `$args`. Since the `-f` operator supports taking an array as input, and we've explicitly said to use the first element `{0:`, we don't need to do the usual `$args[0]`. We encapsulate that string in parens, then index into it `[1,3,0,5,2,7,4,6]` with the weaving. The resultant array is left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

#### Examples

*(the default `.ToString()` for an array has the separator as `` `n ``, so that's why the output is newline separated here)*

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\golf-bit-weaving.ps1 10011101
0
1
1
1
0
1
1
0

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\golf-bit-weaving.ps1 1111
0
0
0
1
0
1
1
1
```

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 17 bytes

```
8é0$7hd|òxplò2|@q
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=OMOpMCQ3aGR8w7J4cGzDsjJ8QHE&input=MTAwMTExMDE)

This takes input and output in binary. Most of the byte count comes from padding it with 0's. If padding the input was allowed, we could just do:

```
òxplò2|@q
```

Thanks to [Martin's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84044/31716) for the method of swapping characters, e.g:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 X   X   X   X
2 1 4 3 6 5 8 7
   X   X   X
2 4 1 6 3 8 5 7
```

Explanation:

```
8é0                 "Insert 8 '0' characters
   $                "Move to the end of the current line
    7h              "Move 7 characters back
      d|            "Delete until the first character
        ò   ò       "Recursively:
         xp         "Swap 2 characters
           l        "And move to the right
             2|     "Move to the second column
               @q   "And repeat our last recursive command.
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), <s>27</s> 26 bytes

```
_1@
&,)}}}=}}=}}=}!{!!{{!"
```

Input and output in base 2. Output is padded.

[Try it online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=XzFACiYsKX19fT19fT19fT19IXshIXt7ISI&input=MTAwMTExMDE)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 19 characters

```
s[@z1.it%2tzP%2z@z6
```

Input and output are base 2.

Far from a Pyth expert, but since no one else has answered with it yet I gave it a shot.

Explanation:

```
s[                # combine the 3 parts to a collection and then join them
  @z1             # bit 1 goes to bit 0
  .i              # interleave the next two collections
    t%2tz         # bits 3,5,7; t is used before z to offset the index by 1
    P%2z          # bits 0,2,4
  @z6             # bit 6 goes to bit 7
```

Comment: This is invalid as this assumed a zero-padded input.

Answer (score 2):

### vi, 27 bytes

```
8I0<ESC>$7hc0lxp<ESC>l"qd0xp3@q03@q
```

Where `<ESC>` represents the Escape character. I/O is in binary, output is padded. 24 bytes in vim:

```
8I0<ESC>$7hd0xpqqlxpq2@q03@q
```

Comment: `<ESC>` needs backticks around it. I'd edit, but I can't figure out 4 more bytes to change...

Comment: @SirBidenXVII Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## [UGL](https://github.com/schas002/Unipants-Golfing-Language/blob/gh-pages/README.md), 50 bytes

```
cuuRir/r/r/r/r/r/r/%@@%@@%@@%@@@%@@%@@%@@@oooooooo
```

[Try it online!](http://schas002.github.io/Unipants-Golfing-Language/?code=Y3V1UmlyL3Ivci9yL3Ivci9yLyVAQCVAQCVAQCVAQEAlQEAlQEAlQEBAb29vb29vb28&input=MTU3)

Repeatedly div-mod by 2, and then `%` swap and `@` roll to get them in the right order.

Input in base-ten, output in base-two.

Answer (score 1):

### Actually, 27 bytes

```
'08*+7~@tñiWi┐W13052746k♂└Σ
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=JzA4Kis3fkB0w7FpV2nilJBXMTMwNTI3NDZr4pmC4pSUzqM&input=JzEn)

This program does input and output as a binary string (output is zero-padded to 8 bits).

Explanation:

```
'08*+7~@tñiWi┐W13052746k♂└Σ
'08*+                        prepend 8 zeroes
     7~@t                    last 8 characters (a[:~7])
         ñi                  enumerate, flatten
           Wi┐W              for each (i, v) pair: push v to register i
               13052746k     push [1,3,0,5,2,7,4,6] (the permutation order, zero-indexed)
                        ♂└   for each value: push the value in that register
                          Σ  concatenate the strings
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 98 Bytes

Input is taken in base-2 as a string, output is also base-2 as a string

```
n=>(n.length<8?n="0".repeat(8-n.length)+n:0,a="13052746",t=n,n.split``.map((e,i)=>t[a[i]]).join``)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I/O as binary strings

```
ùT8 á g6532
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=czI&code=%2bVQ4IOEgZzY1MzI&footer=Vm4y&input=MTU3) - header & footer convert from and to decimal.